# img under anchor tag (a) using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to get this result using xsl transform:

```
<a href="./myImage.jpg">
  <img src="./myImage.jpg" />
</a>
```

and this is my xml node structure:

```
<home>
  <Image url="./myImage.jpg" />
</home>
```

Please hep me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the future, see to it that others can replicate your problem by putting relevant input and desired output, including what have you done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{current()/@url}">
    <img src="{current()/@url}" />
</a>
```

Comment: It is under div, when I put your code inside div it shows error: 'xsl:template' cannot be a child of 'div' element. What should I do in this case?

Comment: just put the `div` inside the template

Comment: Actually div contains other xsl elements too

Comment: can you show the actual source where `<home>
  <Image url="./myImage.jpg" />
</home>` is?

Comment: if you will not show your actual problem, I can only guess. However, I have edited my answer.

Comment: this image is in <xsl:for-each>, so using your updated answer, only first image shows up, rest does not show up. However hyper link is made correctly.

Comment: thanks for the replies, actually there was problem in my xml file, extension of other two images was gif not jpg.